# Are the outbound IPs of a consumption logic app static?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

We have a requirement to call a 3rd party API via a source with a fixed set of IPs. The IPs need to be static.
Since we are already using Logicapps(consumption) to do other processing, my initial thought was to continue using logic apps. I have already checked the concurrency and message size and they are all within acceptable range to use Logicapps.

My only question is on the IP of the Logicapp when it makes an API call. We had explored using Logic apps standard with VNET integration and Natgateway but this adds additional cost. The other option was to use APIM to provide a static IP, but the Logic would need to integrate with AAD for oAuth2 authentication and we would face challenges in managing the AAD tokens. We don't want to call AAD for a new token for each and every execution.

From the portal I can see a set of outbound IPs for my Logicapp.
[image]
I have already tested that the IP exposed is within this list. But I wanted to know if there is a chance that this can change in the future. I was not able to find any concrete Microsoft documentation around this question.

Answer (score 1):

You should always take in account those IPs can change.

Microsoft exposes a downloadable list of Azure Ip Ranges [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519)

> This file contains the IP address ranges for Public Azure as a whole, each Azure region within Public, and ranges for several Azure Services (Service Tags) such as Storage, SQL and AzureTrafficManager in Public.  Service Tags are each expressed as one set of cloud-wide ranges and broken out by region within that cloud.  **This file is updated weekly**. New ranges appearing in the file will not be used in Azure for at least one week. Please download the new json file every week and perform the necessary changes at your site to correctly identify services running in Azure.

You can also get this data using the PowerShell [Get-AzNetworkServiceTag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/get-aznetworkservicetag) in case you want to automate things. Example:

```
$serviceTags = Get-AzNetworkServiceTag -Location westeurope
$logicApps = $serviceTags.Values | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "LogicApps" }
$logicApps.Properties
```

> Region          :
> SystemService   : LogicApps
> ChangeNumber    : 11
> AddressPrefixes : {4.232.111.16/28, 4.232.111.32/27, 13.64.231.196/32, 13.65.39.247/32...}